# Apagar item do gridview de fotos da galeria

Tags: java, android

Estou desenvolvendo um app que contém uma galeria e encontrei um tutorial que mostrava como preencher o GridView com foto tiradas da câmera.

Porém, estou com dificuldade para fazer algo para quando  o usuário quiser apagar algumas das imagens tiradas ter essa função Obrigado desde já

Segue meu código:

```
    public class GaleriaSp extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    Button captureBtn = null;
    final int CAMERA_CAPTURE = 1;
    private Uri picUri;
    private DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    private GridView grid;
    private  List<String> listOfImagesPath;

    public static final String GridViewDemo_ImagePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/GridViewDemo/";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_galeria_sp);

        captureBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.capture_btn1);
        captureBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
        grid = ( GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridviewimg);

        listOfImagesPath = null;
        listOfImagesPath = RetriveCapturedImagePath();
        if(listOfImagesPath!=null){
            grid.setAdapter(new ImageListAdapter(this,listOfImagesPath));
       }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_galeria_sp, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg1) {
        if (arg1.getId() == R.id.capture_btn1) {

            try {
    //use standard intent to capture an image
                Intent captureIntent = new         Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    //we will handle the returned data in onActivityResult
                startActivityForResult(captureIntent, CAMERA_CAPTURE);
            } catch(ActivityNotFoundException anfe){
//display an error message
                String errorMessage = "Whoops - your device doesn't support capturing images!";
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();
            }
        }
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
   //user is returning from capturing an image using the camera
            if(requestCode == CAMERA_CAPTURE){
                Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
                Bitmap thePic = extras.getParcelable("data");
                String imgcurTime = dateFormat.format(new Date());
                File imageDirectory = new File(GridViewDemo_ImagePath);
                imageDirectory.mkdirs();
                String _path = GridViewDemo_ImagePath + imgcurTime+".jpg";
                try {
                    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(_path);
                    thePic.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
                    out.close();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.getMessage();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                listOfImagesPath = null;
                listOfImagesPath = RetriveCapturedImagePath();
                if(listOfImagesPath!=null){
                    grid.setAdapter(new ImageListAdapter(this,listOfImagesPath));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private List<String> RetriveCapturedImagePath() {
        List<String> tFileList = new ArrayList<String>();
        File f = new File(GridViewDemo_ImagePath);
        if (f.exists()) {
            File[] files=f.listFiles();
            Arrays.sort(files);

            for(int i=0; i<files.length; i++){
                File file = files[i];
                if(file.isDirectory())
                    continue;
                tFileList.add(file.getPath());
            }
        }
        return tFileList;
    }

    public class ImageListAdapter extends BaseAdapter
    {
        private Context context;
        private List<String> imgPic;
        public ImageListAdapter(Context c, List<String> thePic)
        {
            context = c;
            imgPic = thePic;
        }
        public int getCount() {
            if(imgPic != null)
                return imgPic.size();
            else
                return 0;
        }

        //---returns the ID of an item---
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        //---returns an ImageView view---
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            ImageView imageView;
            BitmapFactory.Options bfOptions=new BitmapFactory.Options();
            bfOptions.inDither=false;                     //Disable Dithering mode
            bfOptions.inPurgeable=true;                   //Tell to gc that whether it needs free memory, the Bitmap can be cleared
            bfOptions.inInputShareable=true;              //Which kind of reference will be used to recover the Bitmap data after being clear, when it will be used in the future
            bfOptions.inTempStorage=new byte[32 * 1024];
            if (convertView == null) {
                imageView = new ImageView(context);
                imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
                imageView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
            } else {
                imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
            }
            FileInputStream fs = null;
            Bitmap bm;
            try {
                fs = new FileInputStream(new File(imgPic.get(position).toString()));

                if(fs!=null) {
                    bm=BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fs.getFD(), null, bfOptions);
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(bm);
                    imageView.setId(position);
                    imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(150, 150));
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally{
                if(fs!=null) {
                    try {
                        fs.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
            return imageView;
        }
    }
}
```

Aqui arquivo xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
      android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="sptour.hotmail.com.Suporte"
    android:background="#fff">


    <GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/pp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:horizontalSpacing="2dp"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="1dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:paddingTop="4dp" />



    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/ppp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add_photo"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/pp"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/pp"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/pp"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="44dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Existem diversas formas para resolver esse problema. Vou indicar uma dessas formas. Primeiramente você pode usar o método `setOnItemClickListener` que é referente ao clique longo sobre um item no `grid`. Logo após o ideal seria usar um `AlertDialog` para confirmar se o usuário deseja apagar ou não o item selecionado. O código ficaria assim:

```
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() { 
@Override 
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) { 
// DO something 

 listOfImagesPath.remove(position);
 } 
});
```

Mas este caso você estaria removendo apenas a imagem da sua lista, porém não do dispositivo. Para remover do dispositivo, você tem que resgatar a `uri` da sua foto, que seria o endereço de localização onde foi gravado, e excluir de lá também. Veja o código abaixo:

```
File file = new File(enderecoFoto);
file.delete();
```

Use a imaginação. Boa sorte!

Comment: Obg Cleidimar Viana , usei o 1° exemplo que me indicou e funciona mas não apaga nem do meu app nem da galeria nativa, e tem outro problema no onClick ele  chama a função de da zoom na foto, então preciso de algo com checkbox porem não tenho idéia por onde fazer isso, ser você pode me ajuda a resolver esse problema me aajuda muito

Comment: @JeffersonSantos você está aí? Eu vi que você fez a pergunta novamente com outro usuário. Eu vou editar aqui te resolvendo o problema baseado no teu código.